# Refresh Materialized View impact on the DB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, materialized-view, postgresql-9.6

Hi we are running an PostgreSQL 9.6 database in Amazon RDS under a m4.large(2cpu 8gb) and a provisioned IOPS of 1000. The use case is the following: We have a table with several million of registries (4M more or less) and we have created a materialized view with a subset of this table (2M aprox) changing some columns types to be more efficient in querying. Our pg_conf has not been changed, being RDS Postgres' default.

This is our view definition:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW public.customers_mv as
SELECT 
    id,
    gender,
    contact_info,
    location,
    social,
    categories,
    (social ->> 'follower_count')::integer AS social_follower_count,
    (social ->> 'following_count')::integer AS social_following_count,
    (social ->> 'peemv')::float AS social_emv,
    (social ->> 'engagement')::float AS social_engagement,
    (social ->> 'v')::boolean AS social_validated,
    search_vector,
    flags,
    to_tsvector('english',concat_ws(' ','aal0_'||(customers.location ->> 'aal0'),
      'aal1_'||(customers.location ->> 'aal1'),
      'aal2_'||(customers.location ->> 'aal2'),
      'frequent_location_aal0_'||(customers.location -> 'frequent_location' ->> 'aal0'),
      'frequent_location_aal1_'||(customers.location -> 'frequent_location' ->> 'aal1'),
      'frequent_location_aal2_'||(customers.location -> 'frequent_location' ->> 'aal2'),
      'last_post_location_aal0_'||(customers.location -> 'last_post_location' ->> 'aal0'),
      'last_post_location_aal1_'||(customers.location -> 'last_post_location' ->> 'aal1'),
      'last_post_location_aal2_'||(customers.location -> 'last_post_location' ->> 'aal2'),
      'admin_location_aal0_'||(customers.location -> 'admin_location' ->> 'aal0'),
      'bio_location_aal0_'||(customers.location -> 'bio_location' ->> 'aal0'))) as loc_vector
FROM public.customers
WHERE (customers.social -> 'follower_count') > '5000'
AND customers.social ? 'last_posts' 
AND (customers.flags IS NULL OR NOT customers.flags @> '{"destroy": true}'::jsonb);


CREATE INDEX customers_mv_followerc_idx ON customers_mv USING BTREE (social_follower_count);
CREATE INDEX customers_mv_folling_idx ON customers_mv USING BTREE (social_following_count);
CREATE INDEX customers_mv_emv_idx ON customers_mv USING BTREE (social_emv);
CREATE INDEX customers_mv_gin_social_idx ON customers_mv USING GIN (social jsonb_path_ops);
CREATE INDEX customers_mv_partial_social_validated_idx ON customers_mv (social_validated) WHERE social_validated = FALSE;
CREATE INDEX customers_mv_categories_idx ON customers_mv USING gin (categories);
CREATE INDEX customers_mv_gin_location_idx ON customers_mv USING GIN (location jsonb_path_ops);
CREATE INDEX customers_mv_gin_loc_vector ON customers_mv USING gin(loc_vector);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customers_mv_uniq_id_idx ON customers_mv (id);
```

Our view has some columns just for accessing data like `location` or `social` (both jsonb type) and some other like `loc_vector` for querying faster.

**Now the problem:**
The problem occurs when we try to refresh, refresh concurrently or create a new materialized view, when we try to launch the refresh command the CPU or the write IOPS crash the DB.

Here we can se how hard it hits the DB
[image: CPU Usage]

[image]

What would be the ideal setting given our requirements?

Its a problem of increasing infrastructure or maybe a matter of configuration/optimization?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is likely the indexes.

IIRC, refreshing a materialized view drops the existing data and create a new "table" with the current data.

What this does for your indexes is re-index the entire subset of data, which based on your indexes send like a significant workload.

My recommendation would be to not use the built-in materialized views and to instead roll your own equivalent, incrementally updating data so your are only writing stale data/indexes.

The trade off is that this will be much more complex to build out than simply creating a materialized view, and you'll need to consider how you want to track invalidation of stale data.